# How to stop Bootstrap 5 carousel autoslide only for large screens?

Tags: html, css, sass, carousel, bootstrap-5

I have carousel from Bootstrap 5 which needs to stop autoslide only for large screens, but for mobile version i need to have autoslide.
How can I do that if its possible only with html and css/scss?

I know about `data-bs-interval="false"` but this is stopping autoslide for mobile screen too.

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this script at the end of body

```
<script>
    if(window.innerWidth > 1000){
      document.getElementById('carouselExampleControls').dataset.bsInterval = false
    }
</script>
```

this will check the size of window before it loads and set data-bs-interval to false if size is greater then 1000

Comment: but @Kate just remember about changing screen sizes (while rotating tablet or desktop window resize)

Comment: This is not working for me

Answer (score 1):

You can call `interval: false` with javascript. and, also, define window width. Please try as below javascript.

```
var myCarousel = document.querySelector('#carouselExampleControls')
if ($(window).width() > 991) {
var carousel = new bootstrap.Carousel(myCarousel, {
  interval: false
})
}
```

Comment: I would only change this jQuery-like syntax of window and use window object itself

Comment: I can't use jquery

Comment: by default this option not available as you want. So, You will must need to solution with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

After read new [BS5 Carousel Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/carousel/) it works on window resize and finally got an improved, short and easiest way to do it with jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(window).width() < 768) {
            $('#FirstBox').removeClass('active');
            $('#SecondBox').addClass('active');
            $('#ThirdBox').removeClass('active');
            $('#MyCarousel').attr({
                'data-bs-ride': 'carousel',
                'data-bs-pause': 'hover',
                'data-bs-interval': 3000                    
            }).carousel('cycle');
        }
        
        if ($(window).width() >= 768) {
            $('#FirstBox').addClass('active');
            $('#SecondBox').addClass('active');
            $('#ThirdBox').addClass('active');
            $('#MyCarousel').attr({
                'data-bs-interval': false,
                'data-bs-ride': false,
                'data-bs-pause': true
            }).carousel('pause');
        }
    });
    $(window).trigger('resize');
});
```

Comment: Version with document Element used to swap so fast after resizing! This version with jquery is cleaner!

Comment: Only pause and cycle seems not to work on my side cause the Carousel finish to restart! So my final test with unsetting Carousel dataset works fine for me.